# Write to locked file in Mac OS with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, file

How to write to a locked file in Mac OS X using objective c?

I have tried this but it can't seem to overwrite the contents of the locked file (myRecords.conf).

```
chmod(@"/usr/local/myRecords.conf", 0666);

NSString *filePath = [@"/usr/local"
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myRecords.conf"];


// Write to the file
[@"WRITE TO FILE" writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES
                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Comment: Try to look at the NSError?

Answer (score 0):

Locked system files are not supposed to be written to. To unlock file you can go ahead and change the file permissions. To change the file permissions, at times you need to be the owner of the file.

In your case, chances are that chmod is failing - can be because file is not owned by you. Also there are cases where the parent directory (of the file) does
not allow you to write to the file. You can see this from the parent directory's permissions.

Two options are there.

- Run your application with root privileges. This allows you to write to any locked file. But be very careful with this.
- If it is a one time thing, try changing the file's owner/permissions from terminal.